# Rails4-autocomplete: How to add an image to the list of results?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I am using the [rails4-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) gem and it's working pretty well. But I'd like to improve it by adding an image to the each item in the results list.

Is there any way to do it?